# Kendo UI - using history.replaceState to manage back stack / back button navigation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, html5-history

I have a Kendo UI application flow where I don't want the user to be able to step back into a particular set of views (ie, a couple of 'create' views that lead to the 'completed record' view - the user should not re-access those specific create views). This is for a mobile app if that makes a difference.

I know that Kendo can use [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState().C2.A0method) features to some degree, but it looks like they have only implemented pushState (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/router#configuration-pushState), but I believe I would need the [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) method.

Is there a way to take some manual control temporarily without breaking off from the back stack/[backbutton](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/backbutton) widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Kendo has an implementation of replaceState that they have abstracted to `replace`. [See doc here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/application#methods-replace).

It's as simple as calling your next destination.

```
kendo.mobile.application.replace("#baz");
kendo.mobile.application.navigate("#baz");
```